# Sound is stopping after a period of time

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

The code of the mediaplayer (which starts under the comment:  //Code of the mediaplayer begins) is every time called when I click a button. After some time when I click the button, the sound is not played anymore.

It is like : I click for 10 times and it is returning the sound when I click again it stops and does not work anymore. Thanks for looking, If there is any solution comment below! :D

**Logcat**:

E/AudioFlinger: no more track names available

E/AudioFlinger: createTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?

E/AudioTrack: AudioFlinger could not create track, status: -12

E/AudioSink: Unable to create audio track

E/ExtendedNuPlayerDecoder: error in opening audio sink. Could be fatal!!!

**Code of the main activity'*:

```
           public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

private TextView mScoreView;
private TextView mQuestionView;
private Button mButtonChoice1;
private Button mButtonChoice2;
private Button mButtonChoice3;
private String mAnswer;
private int mScore = 0;
private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
Dialog dialog;
Dialog dialog2;
TextView closeButton;
TextView closeButton2;
CheckBox checkBoxmp;
private MediaPlayer mp, mp2;

SharedPreferences mypref;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);



    //Dialog 1
    createDialog();
    Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn);
    dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();

        }
    });

    closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //end Dialog 1

    //Dialog 2
    createDialog2();
    Button dialogButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn2);
    dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.show();

        }
    });


    closeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog2.dismiss();
        }
    });
    //end Dialog 2

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

    final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();

    checkBoxmp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
            editor.putBoolean("playSounds", !isChecked);
            editor.commit();
            if (!isChecked){
                mp.setVolume(1,1);
                mp2.setVolume(1,1);
            }else{
                mp.setVolume(0,0);
                mp2.setVolume(0,0);
            }
        }
    })
    ;


    final boolean playSounds = mypref.getBoolean("playSounds", false);
    checkBoxmp.setChecked(!playSounds);
    if(playSounds){

        mp.setVolume(1,1);
        mp2.setVolume(1,1);
    }
    else{

        mp.setVolume(0,0);
        mp2.setVolume(0,0);
    }





    TextView shareTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share);
    shareTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            myIntent.setType("text/plain");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello!");
            myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My highscore in Quizzi is very high! I bet you can't beat me except you are cleverer than me. Download the app now! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amapps.impossiblequiz");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with:"));
        }
    });

    mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();


    setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action));
    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"

    ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1)).setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.nav_stats:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class));
                    break;
                case R.id.nav_about:
                    startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu3.class));
                    break;
            }

            return true;
        }
    });

    mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
    mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
    mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
    mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

    final List<Button> choices = new ArrayList<>();
    choices.add(mButtonChoice1);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice2);
    choices.add(mButtonChoice3);

    updateQuestion();






    //Code of the mediaplayer begins:

    for (final Button choice : choices) {
        choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                      try {
                          mp = new MediaPlayer();
                          if (playSounds) {
                              mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                          } else {
                              mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                          }

                        mp.reset();
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd("sample.mp3");
                        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        mp.prepare();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer unused) {
                            mp.release();
                            mp = null;
                        }
                    });
                    mp.start();


                    updateScore();
                    updateQuestion();
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    try {
                        mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
                        if (playSounds) {
                            mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
                        } else {
                            mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                        }
                        mp2.reset();
                        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                        afd = getAssets().openFd("wrong.mp3");
                        mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
                        mp2.prepare();

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer unused) {
                            mp2.release();
                            mp2 = null;
                        }
                    });
                    mp2.start();

                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                    intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

//End mediaplayer main code
private void updateQuestion() {
    if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
        mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
        mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber++);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
        intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private void updateScore() {
    mScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(++mScore));

    SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);

    if (mScore > highScore) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
        editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void createDialog() {
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Tutorial");
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_1);
    closeButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT);
}


private void createDialog2() {
    dialog2 = new Dialog(this);
    dialog2.setTitle("Settings");
    dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_2);
    closeButton2 = (TextView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT2);
    checkBoxmp = (CheckBox) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.ckeckBox);


}
```

}

Comment: How long are the samples you are playing? If they aren't long, you may be better off using [`SoundPool`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html).

Comment: They are like 1 second long, is soundpool better? And how could I set up soundpool?

Comment: In general, yes `SoundPool` is more suitable for short audio clips. There should be plenty of examples if you search for them, and the link in my original comment is to the API documentation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how fast are you playing the sounds back to back? Are you clicking the button rapidly or every few seconds?

Comment: rapidly, very fast

Comment: In that case, I don't think the answer about releasing and creating new `MediaPlayer`s below will help. The native code is going to fall behind and you will still run out of resources. You should definitely look into using `SoundPool`.

Comment: I never used it...I do not have any clue about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not releasing `MediaPlayer`s. That could be the reason behind this issue. Without touching most of your logic, one way to do this is:

Make `mp` and `mp2`, `private` members of `QuizActivity`.

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
    private MediaPlayer mp, mp2;
    ...
}
```

Create `MediaPlayer` whenever required, and release it when playback is done.

```
mp = new MediaPlayer();
if (playSounds) {
    mp.setVolume(1, 1);
} else {
    mp.setVolume(0, 0);
}

AssetFileDescriptor afd;
...
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer unused) {
        mp.release();
        mp = null;
    }
});
mp.start();
```

At other places, you will have to perform `null` checks as shown below, before accessing `mp` and `mp2` to avoid NPE.

```
if (null != mp && null != mp2) {
    if (!isChecked) {
        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
        mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
    } else {
        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
        mp2.setVolume(0, 0);
    }
}
```

Other approach would be to add click-listeners only after creating media players.

[This](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#releaseplayer) link sheds more light on `MediaPlayer` release.

And the complete source would look as shown below.

```
public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;

    private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private Button mButtonChoice1;
    private Button mButtonChoice2;
    private Button mButtonChoice3;
    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
    Dialog dialog;
    Dialog dialog2;
    TextView closeButton;
    TextView closeButton2;
    CheckBox checkBoxmp;
    private MediaPlayer mp, mp2;

    SharedPreferences mypref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


        //Dialog 1
        createDialog();
        Button dialogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn);
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //end Dialog 1

        //Dialog 2
        createDialog2();
        Button dialogButton2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dialogbtn2);
        dialogButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog2.show();

            }
        });


        closeButton2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog2.dismiss();
            }
        });
        //end Dialog 2

        SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();

        checkBoxmp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                editor.putBoolean("playSounds", !isChecked);
                editor.commit();
                if (null != mp && null != mp2) {
                    if (!isChecked) {
                        mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                        mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
                    } else {
                        mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                        mp2.setVolume(0, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        final boolean playSounds = mypref.getBoolean("playSounds", false);
        checkBoxmp.setChecked(!playSounds);

        TextView shareTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.share);
        shareTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello!");
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My highscore in Quizzi is very high! I bet you can't beat me except you are cleverer than me. Download the app now! https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=amapps.impossiblequiz");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share with:"));
            }
        });

        mQuestionLibrary.shuffle();

        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action));
        DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); // Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"

        ((NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1)).setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_stats:
                        startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class));
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        startActivity(new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu3.class));
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score_score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

        final List<Button> choices = new ArrayList<>();
        choices.add(mButtonChoice1);
        choices.add(mButtonChoice2);
        choices.add(mButtonChoice3);

        updateQuestion();


        //Code of the mediaplayer begins:

        for (final Button choice : choices) {
            choice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if (choice.getText().equals(mAnswer)) {
                        try {
                            mp = new MediaPlayer();
                            if (playSounds) {
                                mp.setVolume(1, 1);
                            } else {
                                mp.setVolume(0, 0);
                            }

                            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                            afd = getAssets().openFd("sample.mp3");
                            mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                            mp.prepare();

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });
                        mp.start();
                        updateScore();
                        updateQuestion();
                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    } else {
                        try {
                            mp2 = new MediaPlayer();
                            if (playSounds) {
                                mp2.setVolume(1, 1);
                            } else {
                                mp2.setVolume(0, 0);
                            }
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd;
                            afd = getAssets().openFd("wrong.mp3");
                            mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                            mp2.prepare();

                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                                mp.release();
                            }
                        });
                        mp2.start();

                        Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
                        intent.putExtra("score", mScore); // pass score to Menu2
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }


    //End mediaplayer main code
    private void updateQuestion() {
        if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getLength()) {
            mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));
            mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber++);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question! You are very intelligent!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(QuizActivity.this, Menu2.class);
            intent.putExtra("score", mScore);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    private void updateScore() {
        mScoreView.setText(String.valueOf(++mScore));

        SharedPreferences mypref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        int highScore = mypref.getInt("highScore", 0);

        if (mScore > highScore) {
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mypref.edit();
            editor.putInt("highScore", mScore);
            editor.apply();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        return mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item) || super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void createDialog() {
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setTitle("Tutorial");
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_1);
        closeButton = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT);
    }


    private void createDialog2() {
        dialog2 = new Dialog(this);
        dialog2.setTitle("Settings");
        dialog2.setContentView(R.layout.popup_menu1_2);
        closeButton2 = (TextView) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.closeTXT2);
        checkBoxmp = (CheckBox) dialog2.findViewById(R.id.ckeckBox);
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, `reset` and `release` aren't necessarily synchronous on the native side. Resources can still be exhausted by releasing and creating new `MediaPlayer` instances if it is done fast enough. I'd be interested to know if this resolves the issue for this use case. Hopefully the OP will try it.

Comment: Sir I updated the code below in my post, the **mp=null;** / **mp2 = null;** line of code is in grey and it says: The value null assigned to 'mp' is never used

Comment: @ProjectX, I have updated the answer with `null check`. Also note the additional `setVolume` call after creating the media player.

Comment: Sir I updated the code below in my post, the mp=null; / mp2 = null; line of code is in grey and it says: The value null assigned to 'mp' is never used + Is the code right as  did it or what do I have to change?

Comment: I updated my code. The app is instatly crashing ( I can't start it). Error: **Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.setVolume(float, float)' on a null object reference*

Comment: @ProjectX, I have added complete source. Please let me know if it works!

Comment: Hello the sound works now it rests forever thanks for that:D but now is a little problem that when I try to mute/ unmute the app it will not recently muted as I restart the Activity or Switch the Activity and then back or  restart the app

Comment: When I do that the sound is only woking like 5 times not and than it works and then agian not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153434/discussion-between-user3161880-and-projectx).

Comment: Ok, sir would appreciate that